# Swift 4 - Sound board application - Assign multiple button tags to one button programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'll try to explain this the best that I can.
I am creating a Sound board application. All programmatically without the StoryBoard. The application uses UICollectionView to house all the names of the quotes in cells. The quotes are also buttons. Each cell is a button that should correspond with the specific sound wav file.

I'm using star-wars sounds just as a test for the application - it might be easier if I post majority of my code.

I would like to assign the test sound `"blaster-firing"` to the cell name `"Test Name"` and the sound `"yodalaughing"` to the cell name `"Test Name 2"`

I have the code working and cells populating; when you press the names of the cells it only plays the blaster-firing sound, I know that is because I only have 1 button tag set up to button1, this button1 is performing for every cell.

Is it possible to create different button tags to associate with the quotes I have created? I'm not sure what the best way to go about doing this is.

Here is my ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let cellId = "cellId"

 //add different quotes for cells
let quotes = [Quote(name:"Test Name"),
              Quote(name: "Test Name2")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

    navigationItem.title = "Board"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 200/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]

    collectionView?.register(SoundBoardCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return quotes.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SoundBoardCell
    cell.quote = quotes[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (view.frame.width / 1) - 16, height: 100)
}

private func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insertForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
}
```

I also have another class called `SoundBoardCells`

```
class SoundBoardCell: UICollectionViewCell, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

//let testSoundFiles = ["baster-fire", "yodalaughing"]
var audio1 = AVAudioPlayer()
var audio2 = AVAudioPlayer()

var quote: Quote? {
    didSet {
        guard let quoteName = quote?.name else {return}
        button1.setTitle("\(quoteName)", for: .normal)
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
    setCellShadow()
}

func setCellShadow() {

    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.clipsToBounds = false
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 3
}

func setup() {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    self.addSubview(button1)

    do {
        let audioPlayer1 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "blaster-firing", ofType: "wav")
        try audio1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPlayer1!))
    } catch {
        //ERROR
    }

    do {
        let audioPlayer2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "yodalaughing", ofType: "wav")
        try audio2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPlayer2!))
    } catch {

    }

    // button setups
    button1.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)

    button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

}
// button creations
let button1: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.tag = 0
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.cyan, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 150, height: 150)
    return button
}()

@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
   // print(quote!.name! as Any)
    if (sender.tag == 0) {
        audio1.play()
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
}

  struct Quote {
  let name: String?
}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I did not get your idea: do you want each cell to play different audio? And you are trying to find the best way to achieve that, is it correct?

Comment: Stacy you are correct, I would like each cell to play a different sound and want to know the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this temporarily I used a version like Brandons. In my `cellForItemAt` :

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SoundBoardCell
    cell.quote = quotes[indexPath.item]
    cell.button1.tag = indexPath.row // this is the added line
    return cell
}
```

and for my `buttonClicked`

```
 @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
    if (sender.tag == 0) {
        audio1.play()
    }

    if (sender.tag == 1)  {
        audio2.play()
    }
}
```

Still hoping to clean this up using the other methods available, but this is working for now. When I add the other wav files it will be quite a lot of lines of audio files.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions.

First, I would recommend avoid using tags for reference actions. While it can technically work, it can be a little difficult to manage and track.

Second, I'd put your audio management outside of your cell. The cell can track what kind of audio needs to be played, but let it trigger something elsewhere.

For example, I might approach your app in this manner.

Let's define the audio we'd want to play.

```
enum AudioClip {
    case blaster
    case yoda
}
```

If this soundboard app is going to provide the user to create their own, then you might want to build a different data source. But for this example, this would work. I would add this to your `Quote` struct. In fact, you could define the name of the clip in your enum as a computed property and replace your Quote struct.

Then, build an `AudioManager` that can take an `AudioClip` case and play a specific audio clip for it.

This simplifies your cell so that it doesn't need to manage logic for different audio clips. It literally just needs to know the `Quote` for that particular cell. And when that cell is tapped, either the cell or the collection view can tell the `AudioManager` to play that particular audio clip.

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you for the response. I'm going to try to implement this instead of what I have soon. This sounds very efficient.

Comment: @Goose There's a lot to be said for architecting solutions to problems like this. For me, I've found enums to be very useful for cases like this. Whether you're defining a data source for a table or possible button actions, they can really clean up what you're trying to accomplish. I'm glad you find it efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using reusable collection view cells, it is enough to create one audio player per cell and pass sound file names to it.
Try this option:

1. In cellForItemAtIndexPath pass sound file name along with quote to the cell:

   `cell.quote = quotes[indexPath.item]

   cell.soundName = <#yourSoundName#>`
2. In your SoundBoardCell create only one instance of AVAudioPlayer and after setting soundName property initialize audio1 with content of sound file.
3. In button handler method , just perform audio1.play() without tag checking:

   `@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
         audio1.play()
    }`

Comment: I like this approach - not to say the others are not better or easier.. however: should I create another struct like I did "quote" but create is for sounds? also the only instance of AVAudioPlayer I need will be `audio1 = AVAudioPlayer()` , will I need the `do` statement?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no. A button has only one tag.

As others have suggested, button tags are a pretty fragile way to figure out which sound's was tapped.

It's better to figure out which indexPath the cell is mapped to and use that to look up information in your data model. You can get the coordinates of your button, convert them to your collection view's coordinate system, and use the collection view method `indexPathForItem(at:)` to figure out which indexPath was tapped.

I also agree with Josh that you should not put your sound logic in the cells. Have the button action invoke a target/action in the view controller, where you use the sender to figure out which indexPath the button belongs to, look up that sound in your model, and use a sound manager object to play the sound.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, multiple tags on one button may not be a good idea programmatical wise. However, despite those saying it can’t be done, it is possible to create something like it. Create a new button class

```
class ButtonWithMultipleTags: UIButton {
    var tags : [int] = [ ]
}
```

Although that’s not what you’re trying to do. each button created in a cell is its own Object. So you can set each button it’s own tag, it’s not one button that needs multiple tags. If you set cell with indexPath.row 1 to 3, every other button will still have tag 0

But another way to set each button to a specific sound would be something like this: in your uncontroller with your collection view

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SoundBoardCell
     cell.button1.tag = indexPath.row
     cell.button1.addTarget(self, #selector(playAudio(sender:_), .touchDown)
     return cell
 }


 // make an array for your audioSounds
 var audioSounds = [audio1, audio2, audio3]

 // add func for selector that takes from audioquotes
  @objc func playAudio(sender: UIButton){
  audioSounds[sender.tag].play
 }
```

This may not be the best way, but it should work. I’m on my phone so check for minor errors

Comment: A version of your method worked Brandon, all I did was add the `cell.button1.tag = indexPath.row` to the `cellForItemAt` and then kept everything the same in my `buttonClicked` function and added `if(sender.tag == 1) { audio2.play() } I did not make an array for the sounds because that rendered an issue.

Comment: I’m glad that worked! My style was a preference choice as I tend to keep functions out of the cell class(: you would have had to move your cell functions to your controller :P but everyone has their ways! Good luck!